If $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n) \cap L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $\| \phi \|_1 = 1$, then the dillations $\phi_t$ preserve these properties?
Context. Consider the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ and denote by $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ the usual space of measurable functions that are integrable. Moreover, let $C^k(\mathbb R^n)$ denote the space of functions defined on $\mathbb R^n$ that are $k$ times continuously differentiable, where $k \geqslant 1$ is an integer. As usual, define $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ to be the intersection of all $C^k$ and let $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ denote the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb R^n$ with compact support. Furthermore, let $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n) = C_c(\mathbb R^n) \cap C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.
Consider an arbitrary kernel $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n) \cap L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $\| \phi \|_1 = 1$ and define the dillations
$$ \phi_t(x) = t^{-n} \, \phi\left( \frac{x}{t} \right), $$
for every $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $t > 0$.
Question. My goal is to prove the following claim:
$$ \phi_t \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n) \cap L^1(\mathbb R^n) \, \, \, \text{ such that } \, \, \, \| \phi_t \|_1 = 1, \quad \text{ for every }t > 0. $$
My attempt. I believe I was able to prove that $\phi_t \in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ with $\| \phi_t \|_1 = 1$, for every $t > 0$. To do this, I applied a simple change of variables to obtain
$$ \| \phi_t \|_1 = \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\phi_t(x)| \, dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} t^{-n} \Bigg| \phi\left( \frac{x}{t}\right) \Bigg| \, dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} t^{-n}|\phi(u)|t^n \, du = \| \phi \|_1 = 1. $$
On the other hand, I am not sure how to proceed to establish that $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.
Thanks for any help in advance.

That $\phi_t$ is smooth is trivial (multiplication by a constant is smooth). Where do you get stuck?

And the support of $\phi_t$ is simply dilated with respect to the original one.

@Lorago Thanks for your comment. I understand that the factor $t^{-n}$ doesn't change the smoothness. My main problem is understanding that the change in the argument also doesn't change the smoothness. How do you guarantee this ?

$x\mapsto\frac{x}{t}$ is smooth, so $x\mapsto\phi\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)$ is a composition of smooth maps, and is hence smooth

@lcv Can you elaborate on what you mean by a "dilated support" ? Analougously to the smoothness part, I believe that the factor $t^{-n}$ has no influence on the support. More precisely, I believe we should have $$ \text{supp } \phi_t := \overline{ {x \in \mathbb R^n : t^{-n} , \phi\left( \frac{x}{t} \right) \neq 0} } = \overline{ { x \in \mathbb R^n: \phi\left( \frac{x}{t} \right) \neq 0 } }. $$ If this is correct, how do you proceed to show that this is a compact set ?

@Lorago Thanks, I understood your reasoning!

Note that
$$t\{u\in\mathbb{R}^n:\phi(u)\neq0\}=\{tu\in\mathbb{R}^n:\phi(u)\neq0\}=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\phi\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)\neq0\right\},$$
from which it easily follows that
$$\operatorname{supp}\phi_t=t\operatorname{supp}\phi$$
(I'll leave the details to you). This is clearly compact as $\phi$ is compactly supported. The smoothness part we cleared up in the comments. Thus $\phi_t\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Very good, thanks.
